# Command screen.fill() doesnt reset objects on the screen

Tags: python, pygame

Commands screen.fill() or screen.blit(), doesnt refresh my object on the screen. My player's object or biedronka's objects stays in the same position even then my program reset the whole screen. My game runs perfectly and i have only problem with this refreshing screen.  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

…

```
 import os
 import random
 import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Biedronkaaa')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
background_menu = pygame.image.load("tlo-menu.png")
background_game = pygame.image.load("tlo-gra.png")



def write(text, x, y, size):
    cz = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", size)
    text = cz.render(text, 1, (204, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text, (x, y))


class Biedronki():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(10, 100)
        self.y = random.randint(10, 100)
        self.vx = random.randint(-4, 4)
        self.vy = random.randint(-4, 4)
        self.graphic = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('biedrona.png'))
        self.size = 24

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.graphic, (self.x, self.y))


    def moves(self):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy
        if self.x <= 0 or self.x >= 500 - self.size:
            self.vx = self.vx * -1
        if self.y <= 0 or self.y >= 500 - self.size:
            self.vy = self.vy * -1

    def collision(self, player):
        x_srodek = self.x + self.size / 2
        y_srodek = self.y + self.size / 2
        if player.collidepoint(x_srodek, y_srodek):
            return True
        else:
            return False


enemies = []
for i in range(20):
    enemies.append(Biedronki())

# player cords
x_player = 450
y_player = 450
v = 20
player = pygame.Rect(x_player, y_player, 32, 32)
graphic_player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('gracz.png'))

game = "menu"
points = 0

# mainloop
while True:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if y_player - v > 0:
                    y_player -= v
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if y_player + v < 500 - 32:
                    y_player += v
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if x_player + v < 500 - 32:
                    x_player += v
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if x_player - v > 0:
                    x_player -= v
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if game != "contest":
                    screen.blit(graphic_player, (x_player, y_player))
                    game = 'contest'
                    points = 0
            player = pygame.Rect(x_player, y_player, 32, 32)

    if game == "menu":
        screen.blit(background_menu, (0, 0))
        write("Press space to run", 140, 250, 20)
    elif game == "contest":

        points += 1
        screen.blit(background_game, (0, 0))
        for biedroneczka in enemies:
            biedroneczka.moves()
            biedroneczka.draw()
            if biedroneczka.collision(player):
               game = "end"

        screen.blit(graphic_player, (x_player, y_player))
        write(str(points), 30, 30, 20)
        pygame.time.wait(15)

    elif game == "end":
        write("Niestety przegrywasz", 50, 290, 20)
        write("Nacisnij spację, aby zagrać jeszcze raz", 50, 350, 20)
        write("Twój wynik to: " + str(points), 50, 320, 20)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it by added to the space key reseting objects and player position

```
 if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
     if game != "contest":
            screen.blit(graphic_player, (x_player, y_player))
            game = 'contest'
            points = 0
            x_player = 450
            y_player = 450
            for _ in range(20):
                enemies.pop(0)
            for _ in range(20):
                enemies.append(Biedronki())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `pygame.display.update()` at the end of the main loop.

Comment: I did it, however doesnt see here, my game runs perfectly but has one disadvantage with this restart the game

Comment: I will add the whole code(about 110lines) once I reach home

Comment: Sure, I will check it out. But it is a bit hard to understand anything because you wrote the functions in your language. I am also not native English speaker, but it's a good practice to write code in English.

Comment: This program had home's purpose but its fine im gotta change it

Comment: Help! i tried witch changing format to jpg but didnt work anyway again

Comment: Can you please provide the image files, too?

Comment: https://imgur.com/9ICArjP, https://imgur.com/hebKFZE, https://imgur.com/a/Q8zoKI0, https://imgur.com/YQZlM7z (its black guy). I tried to replace these backgrounds with simple screen.fill((0,0,0)) for the whole game but didnt work either